# Using a ItemsSource with binding gives designer-warnings on properties of DataGrid but not on ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, listbox

I have a simple view model like:

```
public class ViewModel {
    public int Number {get;set;}
    public ObservableCollection<SubViewModel> SubModels {get;set;}
}
public class SubViewModel{
    public string SomeText {get;set;}
}
```

And I want to bind this in the xaml.

Now having a binding in a ListBox like:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubModels}">
```

and then using properties from a SubViewModel like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeText}" />
```

gives me no warnings and I even have the "autocomplete" in the designer available.

When doing the same in a DataGrid, Visual Studio shows warnings that it can't find the property "SomeText", since it's looking in the ViewModel class instead of SubViewModel.

When running the application all is fine but this warning and the missing "autocomplete" is quite annoying.

Is there any way to fix this easily?

Edit 1:
Here's the complete source of the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfBindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:wpfBindingTest="clr-namespace:WpfBindingTest"
        d:DataContext="{x:Static wpfBindingTest:SampleDataContext.ViewModel}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Number}"></TextBlock>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubModels}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SomeText}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubModels}" CanUserAddRows="False" HeadersVisibility="Column">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="SizeToCells" MinWidth="50" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=SomeText}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: I just added the xaml code. It seems that it is because of the DataGridTemplateColumn I am using. When using a DataGridTextColumn it seems to work correctly.

Comment: The only way I currently found is to add the DataType "wpfBindingTest:SubViewModel" to all of the DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate, which is not that great.

Comment: I know this question is years old but did you every find a solution to this? I have the same thing and, while it works, it's annoying!

Comment: Unfortunately not until today. Only the workaround described above.